# Google places autocomplete is not showing suggestions always, and when it shows, I am not able select a place

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I tried integrating the Google Places Autocomplete, it was working fine initially, but since yesterday, it is behaving in a peculiar manner.

Sometimes it doesn't loads search results at all :

[Screenshot for normal search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2iUs.png)

And whenever it does (ocassionally), if I try to select a place from the search results, rather than selecting the place, it starts searching for it again.

**Here I got suggestions**

[Screenshot when it actually shows suggestions sometimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlxnr.png)

**I selected Daytona Beach and it started seaching for it instead of selecting it and showed no results**

[Screenshot after I selected a place from the suggestions, it starts searching for it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfqEy.png)

Here's what I did :

1) In app level gradle file

```java
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

2) The code

```java
Places.initialize(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
        autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS,
                Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i("TESTPLACEE", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("TESTPLACEE", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
```

Comment: it shows and when clicked it hides right ?

Comment: It doesn't always shows suggestions, and sometimes when it does, if  I select a place, instead of returning the selected place, it starts searching for it again and shows no results.

Comment: does it shows any error in logs ?

Comment: update your google plug and play version

Comment: Nothing, no errors, it's working but not showing any suggestions most of the time as I said

Comment: And about that updating play version thing, recently I read about it's deprecation and for migration to the latest google places, they asked to remove the play services. Here https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: Have you [fully migrated](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) to the new SDK? Does this issue happen too if you create a brand new project and use the exact code from [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment)? Please share the results of this test.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it in a new project, same issue.

Comment: I see, okay, do you have the Places API enabled on your project? Are you using a correctly restricted API key (from your project)? Have you enabled billing? Please double check.

Comment: Also check that you are not hitting API daily quota limits if you have any. See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#gmp_restricted_regions).

Comment: Yeah, all done.

Comment: Ok this is strange especially if it's happening with the exact code from Google's guide. Does your logcat show no errors at all? What version are you using? Have you added and allowed all required permissions? Have you tried running the app on different emulators? Using another, unrestricted API key? Please post your complete build.gradle and code. Or contact [Maps Platform support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#contact_maps_support).

Comment: @AmarjeetSarma have you resolved the issue? if so, kindly share the resolution..